# Center align only first table row

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, tabu

I'm using the `tabu` package for my tables and this comes with the `X` column type. I defined an `R` column type (`\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}`) based on `X` which I now use in my table to right align all the data.

To fit inside of the page, I need to shrink the table a bit, so I wanted to place the units in a new line. This is possible in `X` cells by typing `\newline`.

This all works well, but now the first line (the descriptions) looks a bit weird, as there is no real alignment. I think it should be aligned to the center. So my question is how I could change the default setting of `R` to `C` for just the first row.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
    \caption{Table 1}

    \centering
    \taburowcolors[1] {white .. gray!10}
    \begin{tabu}[t]{| R R R R R R R |}
        \hline
        $c$ \newline [\si{mol\per\liter}]
            & $V_\text{Tensid}$ \newline [\si{\milli\liter}]
            & $V_\text{Wasser}$ \newline [\si{\milli\liter}]
            & $\Pi_\text{1. Durchgang}$ \newline [\si{\milli\newton\per\meter}]
            & Offset \newline [\si{\milli\newton\per\meter}]
            & $\Pi_\text{2. Durchgang}$ \newline [\si{\milli\newton\per\meter}]
            & Offset \newline [\si{\milli\newton\per\meter}]\\
        \hline
        0.04 & 60 & 0 & 22.6 & 0.7 & - & -\\
        $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$\\
        0.004 & 60 & 30 & 21.6 & 0.6 & 20.7 & 1.3\\
        0.002 & 60 & 60 & 21.0 & 0.3 & 22.1 & 1.4\\
        0.001 & 60 & 60 & 20.9 & 0.2 & 24.3 & 0.7\\
        \hline
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{docum
```

ent}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `tabu` and its flexible width columns, I would use the `S` columns from the `siunitx` package to align the numbers with resprect to the decimal separator. In order to fit the table onto the textwidth I have reduced the horizontal distance between columns (`tabcolsep`). As one can see from the MWE, the column headers are automatically horizontally centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \caption{Table 1}
    \centering
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{| S[table-format=1.3] S[table-format=2] S[table-format=2] S[table-format=2.1] S[table-format=2.1] S[table-format=2.1] S[table-format=1.1] |}
        \hline
              {$c$}
            & {$V_\text{Tensid}$} 
            & {$V_\text{Wasser}$}
            & {$\Pi_\text{1. Durchgang}$}
            & {Offset}
            & {$\Pi_\text{2. Durchgang}$}
            & {Offset}\\
              {[\si{mol\per\liter}]}
            & {[\si{\milli\liter}]}
            & {[\si{\milli\liter}]}
            & {[\si{\milli\newton\per\meter}]}
            & {[\si{\milli\newton\per\meter}]}
            & {[\si{\milli\newton\per\meter}]}
            & {[\si{\milli\newton\per\meter}]}\\
        \hline
        0.04 & 60 & 0 & 22.6 & 0.7 & {-} & {-}\\
        {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$}\\
        0.004 & 60 & 30 & 21.6 & 0.6 & 20.7 & 1.3\\
        0.002 & 60 & 60 & 21.0 & 0.3 & 22.1 & 1.4\\
        0.001 & 60 & 60 & 20.9 & 0.2 & 24.3 & 0.7\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to stick to `tabu` and right aligned numbers, you might be interested in using the `\makecell` command from the eponymous package.

Comment: Your idea with the `S` column is great. I didn't know that one! But why shouldn't I use it inside of `tabu`? It works well :)

Comment: @Sam: One typically uses `tabu` in combination with its `X` columns that enable automated line breaking of long texts in table cells. As there are no long texts in the table, using `tabu` for this particular table simply is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like I am a bit late for this answer but still here is my input.

Beatiful typesetting, but not so elegant code. I used multicolumn to cheat the aligment. It also requires some manual tuning of the column width, which can be a pain if you're in a hurry or have too many columns.

I included the `threeparttable` because it's a easy way to add table notes. The `booktabs` package is what allows this table to look so much better (IMO) without extra custom command definitions etc.

[image: table with booktabs and wrap text inside multicolumn]

Note how the `\vdots` get shifted to the decimal alignment. As pointed by leandriis this is due to the missing `table-format` option on the `S`. Which consistis of two numbers, the first the integer and second is the decimal.
So to make it center alignment I did this:

```
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.3]S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=1.1]S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=1.1]}
```

[image: S with table-format]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{.75ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Some Science Experiment}\label{table:experiment1}
\rowcolors{1}{white}{gray!10}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.3]S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=1.1]S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=1.1]} %use l if you want numbers left aligned
\toprule
 \multicolumn{1}{p{3em\relax}}{\centering $c$ [\si{mol\per\liter}]} 
& \multicolumn{1}{p{2.5em\relax}}{\centering $V_\text{Tensid}$ [\si{\milli\liter}]}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{3em\relax}}{\centering $V_\text{Wasser}$ [\si{\milli\liter}]}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{5em\relax}}{\centering $\Pi_\text{1. Durchgang}$  [\si{\milli\newton\per\meter}]}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{4em\relax}}{\centering Offset  [\si{\milli\newton\per\meter}]}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{5em\relax}}{\centering $\Pi_\text{2. Durchgang}$  [\si{\milli\newton\per\meter}]}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{4em\relax}}{\centering Offset [\si{\milli\newton\per\meter}]}
  \\
\midrule
        0.04 & 60 & 0 & 22.6 & 0.7 & {-} & {-}\\
        {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$} & {$\vdots$}\\
        0.004 & 60 & 30 & 21.6 & 0.6 & 20.7 & 1.3\\
        0.002 & 60 & 60 & 21.0 & 0.3 & 22.1 & 1.4\\
        0.001 & 60 & 60 & 20.9 & 0.2 & 24.3 & 0.7\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item  Source or other notes.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The shift of the vdots that you observe seems due to the usage of `S` type columns without the usage of the `[table-format] ` option.